# Highcharts Tooltip on first data entry missing

Tags: highcharts

In the chart that I am creating there is no tooltip on the first data entry. The graph is aligned with no margins within a container so that the first data entry is the border of the xAxis on the left and last data entry is the edge of the graph on the right.
On the example I am giving the link to, it will show the tooltip when you resize the graph into a smaller version (pictures attached).

Does anyone know why the tooltip is missing?

Here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-vaughan-3610d?file=/src/Graph.tsx) to code online

[image: With the tooltip on first data entry]

[image: Without the tooltip on first data entry]

Comment: Not sure but I think it might be something to do with the selector below. Even without resizing, if I drag the selector below to the left, I can see tooltip on the first point. I think by default selector is scrolled to the right

Comment: I see your point, but dragging the selector to the left didn't enable the tooltip for me.

Comment: Hi Lukasz, Your problem seems to be a Highcharts bug which is related with update of a specific options combination. I have simplified the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/25cLn1ky/ You can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues As a workaround update the chart only by changed configuration, example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-violet-34no-34nop?file=/src/Graph.tsx

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ppotaczek. I'm looking into the solution now.